# Удаления элемента из списка

Tags: c++, классы, списки

Здравствуйте! Проблема состоит в том, что я не могу удалить последний элемент из списка.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class catalog {
    struct books {
        char name[20];
        char autor[10];
    };
    struct elem {
        books data;
        elem * pnext;
    };
    public: void add();
    void show();
    void find_by_autor(char * autor);
    void dell();
    elem * plist = NULL, * pfirst;

};

void catalog::add() {
    elem * tmp = new elem;
    cout << "input name of book ";
    cin >> tmp - > data.name;
    cout << "input autor of book ";
    cin >> tmp - > data.autor;
    if (!plist) {
        tmp - > pnext = NULL;
        plist = tmp;
        pfirst = plist;
    } else {
        plist - > pnext = tmp;
        pfirst = plist;
    }
}

}
void catalog::dell() {

}
```

Comment: Конечно не можете у вас же метод dell() пустой! Хахаха

Comment: @Bandidi, Вы бы спецификации к функциям на русском языке (это такие комментарии, в которых описывается что и с какими данными функция должна делать) написали. 

Тогда, может кто и захочет помочь. А так, прикажете гадать, что Вы думали получить?

Comment: @Bandidi, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему у вас и add неверно написан. 
Попробуйте так, у меня pfirst - первый элемент списка, plast - последний, доабавление происходит в конец. Кож может не компилиться из-за орфографических ошибок(я его не проверял), нужно будет поправить.

```
void catalog::add() {
    elem * tmp = new elem;
    cout << "input name of book ";
    cin >> tmp - > data.name;
    cout << "input autor of book ";
    cin >> tmp - > data.autor;
    tmp - > pnext = NULL;

    if (!plist) {
        plist = tmp;
        pfirst = plist;
    } else {
        plist - > pnext = tmp;
        plist = tmp;
    }
}

}
void catalog::dell() {
    elem * tmp = pfirst;
    while (tmp - > pnext != plist) {
        tmp = tmp - > pnext;
    }
    tmp - > pnext = NUll;
    delete plist;
    plist = tmp;
}
```